# SDL text box highlighting text

Tags: c++, text, textbox, sdl, highlight

I am making a program in C++ that uses SDL to display text boxes. I've made the basic functions of my text boxes like typing text, limitations, copy/paste, *etc.* but I am stuck at make it able to highlight text.

**Here's how I draw textboxes:**

```
void draw_text_box(SDL_Surface *screan, char *message, struct textbox *text_box, int r, int g, int b)
{
    int temp_width;
    int temp_frame;
    SDL_Surface *text;
    SDL_Color textcolor = {0,0,0,0};
    SDL_Rect temp_location, clr_box;

    temp_width = text_box->location.w; //preserve the correct width

    temp_location = text_box->location;
    temp_location.y += 4;
    temp_location.h = 12;

    clr_box = text_box->location;

    //colors!
    textcolor.r = r;
    textcolor.g = g;
    textcolor.b = b;

    //text = TTF_RenderText_Solid(ttf_font, text_box->prev_message, textcolor);
    //SDL_BlitSurface( text, NULL, screan, &text_box->location);//<-changes "location" width to width of text

    //clear
    SDL_FillRect(screan, &clr_box, SDL_MapRGB(screen->format, 0, 0, 0));

    //strcpy(text_box->prev_message, message);

    //set the text
    text = TTF_RenderText_Solid(ttf_font, message, textcolor);

    if(!text) return;

    //set the offset
    temp_location.x = text_box->last_shift;
    temp_location.y = 0;
    temp_location.h = text->h;

    if(text_box->cursor_loc - text_box->last_shift > temp_location.w)
    temp_location.x = text_box->cursor_loc - temp_location.w;

    if(text_box->cursor_loc - 3 < text_box->last_shift)
    temp_location.x = text_box->cursor_loc - 3;

    if(temp_location.x < 0) temp_location.x = 0;
    text_box->last_shift = temp_location.x;

    //draw
    SDL_BlitSurface( text, &temp_location, screan, &text_box->location);//<-changes "location" width to width of text
    text_box->location.w = temp_width;
}
```

**Setting the text:**

```
void set_text_box_text(SDL_Surface *screan, struct textbox *text_box, char *message)
{
    if(text_box->message != message)
        strcpy(text_box->message, message);

    text_box->char_amt = strlen(message);
    text_box->cursor = text_box->char_amt;
    text_box->last_shift = 0;

    if (screan) //if not NULL
    {
        if (text_box->selected)
            select_text_box(screan,text_box);
        else
            unselect_text_box(screan,text_box);
    }
    else
    {
        ;//text_box->prev_message[0] = '\0';
    }
}
```

**Select and deselect the textbox:**

```
void select_text_box(SDL_Surface *screan, struct textbox *text_box)
{
    char temp_message[405] = "";
    char temp_left[405];
    int i;

    text_box->selected = 1;

    if (text_box->pass_char == '\0')
    {
        if (text_box->cursor != 0)
        {
            left(temp_left, text_box->message, text_box->cursor);
            strcat(temp_message, temp_left);
        }

        temp_message[text_box->cursor] = '|';
        temp_message[text_box->cursor + 1] = '\0';

        right(temp_left, text_box->message, text_box->cursor);
        strcat(temp_message, temp_left);
    }
    else
    {
        for(i=0;i<text_box->cursor;i++)
            temp_message[i] = text_box->pass_char;

        temp_message[i] = '|';

        for(i++;i<text_box->char_amt + 1;i++)
            temp_message[i] = text_box->pass_char;

        temp_message[i] = '\0';
    }

    draw_text_box(screan, temp_message, text_box, 250, 250, 250);

}

void unselect_text_box(SDL_Surface *screan, struct textbox *text_box)
{
    char temp_message[405];
    int i;

    text_box->selected = 0;

    if (text_box->pass_char == '\0')
        draw_text_box(screan, text_box->message, text_box, 250, 250, 250);
    else
    {
        for(i=0;i<text_box->char_amt;i++)
            temp_message[i] = text_box->pass_char;

        temp_message[i] = '\0';
        draw_text_box(screan, temp_message, text_box, 250, 250, 250);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please post a [minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that we can help you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is difficult to answer as it doesn't contain your code. You'll need to post your code so that people can look at it and explain how to proceed. It's preferred that you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You can use the [edit] button to update your question. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! Question updated.